# How to create a rule in a web.config file for a C# application, to block based on parameters in the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I want to create filter rule in the web.config file for a C# application, to block http://website.com/folder/Default.aspx, 
but allow http://website.com/folder/Default.aspx?db=Database. Basically they don't have "Default.aspx?db=Database" in the URL, then it will either redirect them to a website another website (or Deny access).

Comment: You could put that logic in PageLoad, what is your reason for wanting a filter rule?

Comment: The C# application is lost, If I can make a modification in the web.config that would be great. Otherwise I will have to recreate the project.

Comment: Moral of the story: use [source code control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_version_control_software).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement an HttpModule that performs your desired logic. You can register it in the web.config without any code changes to the project. Just compile it into its own dll and drop that into the bin folder of your website.

The module

```
class RequestInterceptor : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    // In the Init function, register for HttpApplication 
    // events by adding your handlers.
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest += (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));
    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source,
         EventArgs e)
    {

        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;

        //Inspect the URL and decide if this is a request you are interested in
        //context.Request.Url
        //context.Request.QueryString

        //Redirect, or whatever...
        //context.Response.Redirect(...)

    }
}
```

The web.config:

```
<system.webServer>    
    <modules>
      <add name="MyInterceptor" type="YourNamespace.RequestInterceptor, RequestInterceptor"/>
    </modules>
...
```

Comment: it was in the App_Code, that is what my problem was. Thank you